# CollectionView, SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}" Didn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I am trying to bind the "SelectedItems" property of my CollectionView between my View and my ViewModel. But the TwoWay didnt work.

I can send information to my View, but i cant send information to my ViewModel.

( all another biding works correctly )

Some code,in my ViewModel :

```
        private ObservableCollection<Element> _selectedElement;
        public ObservableCollection<Element> SelectedElement
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedElement;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedElement != value)
                {
                    _selectedElement = value;

                }
            }
        }
```

in my view

```
<CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Elements,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             SelectionMode="Multiple"
                             SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            
                            <StackLayout   Padding="15,10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding Libelle}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Code}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                <ImageButton Source="{Binding ImgFavori}"
                                                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                 Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ManageFavCommand, Source={x:Reference CurrentView}}"
                                                 CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                 WidthRequest="75" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            
                            </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

When i use the ViewModel for manipulate the view like this :

```
private async void ClearCollection()
{
    SelectedElement = null;
}
```

that's work.

But when i try to select some line on my smartphone, i never pass in the setter of SelectedElement.

I am using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2196

Thx for help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your help I found my problem.

I dont need to use the SelectionChangedCommand ( he work but i dont need this event, i just need data )

But trying your answer, i added this :

```
SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding .}
```

And now my IList SelectedElement has the data selected in my view !

Thx for help me.

Comment: Small comment - just stuck with that question as well. SelectionChangedCommandParameter wasn't necessary for me, just changing ObservableCollection<Element> to IList<object> helped

Answer (score 1):

Two changes needed:

1. The type of the bound property (`SelectedElement`) must match the type of the CollectionView property (`SelectedItems`).
   [XF Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selecteditems?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_SelectableItemsView_SelectedItems) says the type is `IList<object>`.
2. Your bound property (if the correct type) will get set to the SelectedItems list when the binding is resolved (page is loaded; BindingContext set). It starts out as an empty list. As selection changes, the list's **contents** change. **But the list object itself is the same object, so the setter never gets called again.**

So how do you see a change? Via either [`SelectionChangedCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selectionchangedcommand?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_SelectableItemsView_SelectionChangedCommand), or [`SelectionChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selectionchanged?view=xamarin-forms).

---

To use `SelectionChangedCommand`:

add to CollectionView XAML:

```
<CollectionView ... SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" ...>
```

Add to view model (your BindingContext):

```
    // There's no point in customizing this setter, because it won't get called when you want it to.
    public IList<object> SelectedElement { get; set; }

    // in constructor:
         SelectionChangedCommand = new Command(SelectionChanged);

    public Command SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    private void SelectionChanged(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedElement != null && SelectedElement.Count > 0) {
            var element = SelectedElement[0] as Element;
            ...
        }
    }
```